# Display [object Object] in html Angular

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, html-table

I have a problem to display data array in table.

I have component.html

```
<div class="row">      
  <table class="bordered table-bordered" [mfData]="hbps| dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable"   [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage" [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <mfDefaultSorter by="serial_number">Serial Number</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>
        <th>
          <mfDefaultSorter by="sensor_serial">Sensor Serial</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
        <td>{{item.serial_number}}</td>
        <ul><li>{{item.sensors[0].sensor_serial}}</li></ul>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
          <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5,10,15]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>   </table> </div>
```

component.ts

```
>       public hbps: HBPS[];
>     
>       ngOnInit() {
>         this.ws.hbpsGetAll().subscribe(
>           hbps=> {
>             this.hbps= hbps;
>           }
>         );
>       }
```

ws send me this data

- *{"StatusCode":0,"StatusMessage":"OK","StatusDescription": [{"homeboxpackage_id":"1","active":0,"homebox_id":"11","serial_number":"serialn1","user_id":"31",
  "sensors":{ "0":{"sensor_serial":"sensorserial1",
  "sensors_id":"11E805BA6732C3DB"},
  "1":{"sensor_serial":"sensorserial2",
  "sensors_id":"11E805BA6F1E6CE9"},
  "2":{"sensor_serial":"sensorserial3",
  "sensors_id":"11E805BA7716C775"}}}]*

And, my object sensors: string[]

Can you help me to display all array sensors in cell of the table.